# Unable to get authorization CODE on Blackboard Learn

Tags: blackboard

I had subscribed and installed "Blackboard Learn for REST and LTI Developers" on the AWS. The instance is running fine.
I have also registered with developer.blackboard.com and got Application Key, Secret and Application ID. According to the documentation, I have also set up the REST API Integrations section in the blackboard instance.

Now I want to implement the OAuth 2.0 flow and I think I did all according to the documentation(https://developer.blackboard.com/portal/displayApi/Learn?version=3500.7.0), but I am unable to get the authorization CODE.

Following is the URL I have called to get the authorization CODE. When I hit the URL in a browser, my test application (ASP.NET MVC, C#) is not receiving any CODE, instead, it is getting an error, error_description and state value. The CODE parameter is null.

```
code = null
state = 1234
error = invalid_request
error_description = invalid client_id
```

I am calling the URL:

```
https://<Public DNS>/learn/api/public/v1/oauth2/authorizationcode?redirect_uri=https://localhost:44300/Home/OAuth2Response&response_type=code&client_id=<Application key>&scope=read&state=1234
```

Am I missing anything? Please help.

NOTE: Release 3500.7.0-rel.10+58ec50a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After configuring with Let's Encrypt SSL Certificates to the Blackboard Learn instance, fixed the issue. The detailed information is available at the link

https://docs.blackboard.com/rest-apis/learn/sandbox/developer-ami

Comment: Can you put more information here about the fix?  The URL no longer works.

Comment: @Malvineous Could you check the updated URL?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think the takeaway message is that the LTI has to be hosted over HTTPS or it won't work.